# Building apps for Android using Python

Tags: android, python, mobile

I primarily program in Python and have always tried to steer clear of Java (no particular reason, really). Now I find myself in a position where I have to build an app for Android.

My question is, is there any inherent difference in terms of speed, resource-consumption, access to hardware features etc if I build the app in Python, using SL4A or Kivy or some other platform(I still need to explore those options in detail)? Or should I Download the SDK Bundle and go about learning to build apps for Android exclusively?

Comment: If you use SL4A you just invoke the jar android privide you. Maybe they are same in basement.

Comment: I'd say your best route is to learn how to build Android apps via the Android SDK. I'm in the same boat as you, I was mainly a Python developer beforehand but now I love doing Android development. With the Python libraries, I feel that you lose a lot of the native features of Android, along with access to the libraries that can be used with it. For starters, I'd start learning the Android SDK and then experiment with Python libraries later.

Comment: I've upvoted your question, just because avoiding Java at all cost strikes me as a very good move. :V

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, neither of the projects you mention is meant for building native Android apps. If you were really knowledgeable in Jython and Android, maybe you could finagle Jython to make native apps, but since you mention that you've never used Java, that's unlikely. Unfortunately, the only project that attempted to do it is dead (and turned into SL4A, maybe?).

So TL;DR, if you want completely native, I-can't-believe-it's-not-Java experience, you have no choice. If not, you should specify what exactly you wan't to accomplish, maybe Python is good enough.